# python- Trouble Converting User Input to Integer Format

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
user_input = ("Enter a number and I will tell you the sum of the multiples of 3 and 5 leading up to it.")
number = int(user_input)
```

I am simply trying to obtain input from the user and do certain tests on it. For example, if number > 0:. In order to do this, I assumed that user input data is automatically stored as a string and to remedy this, one would do what is provided in the code box. However, when doing this operation, I get ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Enter a number and I will tell you the sum of the multiples of 3 and 5 leading up to it.' Clearly I am doing this wrong. Can someone shed light on how to do this correctly?

-Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

You are not actually prompting for a number. The `user_input` in your example is the string literal `Enter a number and I will tell you the sum of the multiples of 3 and 5 leading up to it.`, which can not be converted to a number.

User input can be prompted with `input()`.

```
user_input = input("Enter a number and I will tell you the sum of the multiples of 3 and 5 leading up to it.")
number = int(user_input)
```

Comment: Hi @AlpineXJedi if this has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.